# Error while importing large .sql file into MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, import

I am trying to import my backup .sql file into MySQL. I've tried using phpmyadmin, but that didn't allow my large sized file.

My file size is 243 MB. I've made changes in php.ini. The problem is out of 1.1M records, its importing only 600k records. I've tried with MySQL console also using command. Same thing happened with that also. I am using MySQL Workbench, and it showed me below error.

```
ERROR at line 695259: Unknown command '\a'.
Finished executing script
Operation failed with exitcode 1
```

What does this mean? How do I import my full data?

Comment: Let's take a look at line number 695259 and what is your import command?

Comment: Take a look at this [**POST**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12000697/copying-a-mysql-database-generates-error-unknown-command-when-importing)

Comment: From where can I check line number 695259? In mysql console, I tried: mysql -u username -p databasename < yoursqlfile.sql , while mysql workbench, I clicked on data import wizard and follow the steps.

Comment: mysql console isn't the only tool in your computer. There is something called a text editor. There is cat, less, grep if you are on linux

Comment: did you try to import it using navicat?

Comment: I am on windows. Using wamp and mysql workbench. No Ive not tried it usign navicat..

Comment: you mean.. you dump sql file using workbench?

Comment: Its showing <br> at the end of the record. Why its showing only 6 lacs data in that .sql file? I've total 11 lac data in it.

Comment: split your file into 4 to 5 parts and zip those files separately and try to upload the zip files. It worked for me.

Comment: Don't use the word lac, no one outside of india will understand you. The error is not in your import but in your original export. You have probably exported the data using phpmyadmin and it has timed out halfway through

Comment: Oh. You mean it was exported only half data?

Comment: @e4c5: Please post your last comment as answer.

Comment: Thank you. I felt it was too short to be an answer. Wrote it up a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The presence of the `<br/>` tag at the tail of your dump file indicates that you have probably used phpmyadmin to create it and the the page timed out while the dump was in progress. Thus the error is not in your import process but in your dump process.

How can this be fixed? A global solution is to increase the php script execution time with [set_time_limit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) an alternative is to use the mysql console client to create the dump by passing phpmyadmin.

A somewhat tedius but workable solution is to dump one table at a time. This doesn't always work (for example if one table makes up most of the size of the database it might still cause a timeout)

Comment: Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 1):

It seems dump was not properly created. There are few errors in you sql file.