# Export from PHPMyAdmin won't import

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a problem that an export from PHPMyAdmin won't reimport. It's something to do with a combination of an escaped single quote and an   character. I have reduced it to the following:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `text` text NOT NULL,
  `text2` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

With no escaped single quote, but with an  :

```
INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `text`, `text2`) VALUES (108, 'Whats new for local authorities?', '&nbsp;');
```

WORKS OK

With an escaped single quote, but no

```
INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `text`, `text2`) VALUES (108, 'What\'s new for local authorities?', '');
```

WORKS OK

But with both:

```
INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `text`, `text2`) VALUES (108, 'What\'s new for local authorities?', '&nbsp;');
```

Fails with:

```
Static analysis:

1 errors were found during analysis.

Ending quote ' was expected. (near "" at position 100)
SQL query:

INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `text`, `text2`) VALUES (108, 'What\'s new for local authorities?', '&nbsp

MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''&nbsp' at line 1
```

This is probably my ignorance, but I've been exporting and importing large DBs for years with no problems.

Any help, gratefully received.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error while importing large .sql file into MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38583500/error-while-importing-large-sql-file-into-mysql)

Answer (score 2):

Try to import the data from `mysql.exe`

```
mysql -uuser -ppass dbName < file.sql
```

Comment: PHPMyAdmin sometimes does not import the same data it exports.

Comment: PHPMyAdmin doenst handle escaped characters that well even though it exports them in that format.

Comment: Damn I had to use my faithful HeidiSQL. 
I had issues before after exporting tables from PhpMyAdmin, but it had been a while till today :)